# Javascript/NodeJS passing byref

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm still learning JS. In some other languages, you can pass variables byref and then modify them elsewhere in code.

In an attempt to avoid having lots of duplicate code, I have structured a series of callbacks and parsing like so:

```
class MarketData {
   constructor() {
      //Arrays
      this.OneMinuteData = [];
      this.ThreeMinuteData = [];
      this.initializeCandleData();
   }

   initializeData() {
      var client = new Client();
      this._initializeData(60, client, this.OneMinuteData);
      this._initializeData(180, client, this.ThreeMinuteData);
   }

   _initializeData(granularity, client, dataStore) {
      client.GetRates({ granularity: granularity }, function(err, msg, data) {
         var items = data.map(item => ({
            ///data mapped here
         }));
         dataStore = dataStore.concat(items);
      }
}
```

So essentially I have this 'private' `_initializeData` function with the hopes of passing in an array and having it add to the array, but since JS passes byval, I cannot achieve the desired effect (e.g. this.OneMinuteData array is not modified).

Because of this, the only way I currently know how to work around this problem is to essentially have the same function copy-pasted for each individual array, which I find incredibly sloppy. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: It's very difficult to understand your problem from the question and the code posted. Like, what is `this` where those array properties are declared?

Comment: @Pointy essentially I have an object that has arrays for OneMinuteData and ThreeMinuteData. Each of those gets data from the same API call but with different parameters. I have implemented `_initializeData` to try to wrap that API call into a dynamic one by passing in the desired parameter (int in seconds/60 = One Minute) and destination array (60 => this.OneMinuteArray) but the way I'd like to pass the destination array by reference doesn't work.

This is all inside of a class. I'll update the OP accordingly.

Comment: Have one common global object for arrays that needs to be changed frequently

Comment: JavaScript is always pass-by-value, that's true, but all object values are *references* to the object. Thus the *reference* passed is a copy, but the actual array that's manipulated by the function is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but since JS passes byval, I cannot achieve the desired effect (e.g. this.OneMinuteData array is not modified).

While JavaScript does pass by value, that value when dealing with an object (including any array) is a reference.

See [the documentation for concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

So when you say `dataStore = dataStore.concat(items);`, you assign a new array to the local `dataStore` variable and discard the old one.

Outside the function, the original array is unchanged.

The reason the array assigned to `OneMinuteData` is not modified is because you never modify **any** array.

Push the values of `items` into `dataStore` instead.

```
dataStore.push.apply(dataStore, items);
```

---

NB: `GetRates` has the signature of an asynchronous function, so make sure you don't try to inspect the modifications to `OneMinuteData` before they are made.